# Make a button visible if a key is press down

Tags: vba, button, ms-access-2007, keypress

I am trying to make a button visible only if a key (example Control) is press down.

My code:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode = 17 Then
Me.btn1.Visible = True
Else
Me.btn1.Visible = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
Me.btn1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

I need to have visible and active the button only when the CONTROL key is press down and the user click on btn1.

Thank you.

Update Code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnHide_Click()
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmDemo", acSaveYes
End Sub

Private Sub btnFake_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    If vbKeyControl = 17 Then
        Me.btnHide.Visible = True
        FormTimer
        Me.btnFake.SetFocus
        Me.btnHide.Visible = False
    Else
        Me.btnHide.Visible = False
    End If
Exit_This_Sub:
    Exit Sub
Err_Handler:
    If Err = 2467 Then '<== Form is closed.
        Resume Exit_This_Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    End If
Resume Exit_This_Sub
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.btnHide.Visible = False
    Me.btnFake.SetFocus
End Sub

Sub FormTimer()
Dim PauseTime, Start, Finish, TotalTime    
    PauseTime = 0.1    ' Set duration.
    Start = Timer    ' Set start time.
        Do While Timer < Start + PauseTime
            DoEvents    ' Yield to other processes.
        Loop
End Sub
```

I test it and it is working fine. Simple code.
If CONTROL is press btnHide is visible for 0.1sec.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use the `Shift` parameter to tell if they are holding down the `Control` key. `Shift` will be equal to 2.

Comment: `Me.btn1.Visible = KeyCode = 17 And Shift = 2`; any `If ...Then foo = x Else foo = y` conditional block can be simplified to a one-liner Boolean assignment. Also I'd suggest using the `vbKey` constants instead of hard-coding keycodes, for readability.

Comment: But the Form Keydown event is only triggered if there is no active control with the focus. So if a textbox has the focus, the Form Keydown event doesn't trigger

Comment: SO if you put the same code above in the Btn1_Keydown event, your code will work